# Localization Query

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Say I have three tables Type, Translation and Language
Type has a list

```
First
Second
Third
```

Translations will have values for that Type list in each of 2 langauges

```
Value1  german
Value1  french
Value2  german
Value2  french
```

etc...

Currently I am using a stored procedure that accepts the language to read from the Type table and overwrite the value if a translated value exists in the Translation table (if not just return the value from the Type table) ... hope that makes sense.

The Stored Procedure I am using now would be something like this.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetTypesLocalized]   
 -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here   
 @languageId int 
AS  
BEGIN  
 -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from  
 -- interfering with SELECT statements.  
 SET NOCOUNT ON;  

    -- Insert statements for procedure here  
 SELECT ISNULL(tr.Name, t.Name) AS Name,  
 FROM Type AS t  
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Translation AS tr ON  
   (tr.FK = t.Id AND tr.Type = 'type' AND tr.LanguageId = @languageId)  
END
```

How would I represent that query in EF with linq syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var query = from t in db.Type
            from tr in db.Translation
            where t.Id == tr.FK && tr.Type == "type" && tr.LanguageId == langId
            select tr.Name == null ? t.Name : tr.Name;
```

Comment: excellent! The bit I was missing was the double from (embarrassed ... didn't know about that)

Comment: @mjames yes, you can't do join on several conditions in Linq, so only double *from* with *where*